# SQLite Query returning entire database

Tags: c#, sqlite

First of all, I'm using C#, as well as the C# wrapper for SQLite.

I am attempting to query my SQLite database using the following code, but it continually returns the entire database instead of what is expected. I am extremely new to sql queries, so please look over my query and let me know if you see anything that might be causing the problem.

```
public DataTable queryDatabase(String column, String filter)
    {
        string SQL = "SELECT " + column + " FROM SUBCONTRACTOR " + filter;
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(SQL);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

And here is the code I'm running to call the above method...

```
dataGridView.DataSource = sqliteQuery.queryDatabase("*", "WHERE GLOPolicy != 'True' OR ALPolicy != 'True' OR WCPolicy != 'True' OR ULPolicy != 'True' AND BusinessName LIKE '%" + bySubBusinessNameMaskedTextBox.Text + "%' AND Contact LIKE '%" + bySubContactNameMaskedTextBox.Text + "%'");
```

Thanks for any help, as always!

**EDIT:**
With my query, I am attempting to select all records that have...

(GLOPolicy != true OR ALPolicy != true OR WCPolicy != True OR ULPolicy != True)

AND

BusinessName LIKE [business name variable here]

AND

ContactName LIKE [contact name variable here]

Comment: We can only guess, but I would guess that your WHERE clause actually matches all records in the database.

Comment: Not sure on the rules for SQLLite,  but maybe you need a bracket around all those OR clauses?  Depends on what your intention is...

Comment: All I really wanted was for someone to look over my query, because no, it doesn't match all the records in the database. @James: where would the bracket go? And do you mean bracket or parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James is right (in comment).
Because `AND` has [higher precedence](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) than `OR`, your `WHERE` clause essentially says:

```
WHERE 
    GLOPolicy != 'True' OR ALPolicy != 'True' OR WCPolicy != 'True' OR 
    (ULPolicy != 'True' AND BusinessName LIKE '%x%' AND Contact LIKE '%y%')
```

You can fix by adding parens around all `OR`d conditions to ensure that they are evaluated before getting mixed in with the `AND`s:

```
WHERE 
    (GLOPolicy != 'True' OR ALPolicy != 'True' OR WCPolicy != 'True' OR 
    ULPolicy != 'True') AND BusinessName LIKE '%x%' AND Contact LIKE '%y%'
```

Also: I think that your code is vulnerable to [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  I am not fluent in C#, but there should be some built-in way to pass parameters to your query.

---

Edit:
It now seems, in the comments, that there is something else going on here.
I would suggest the following debugging methods:

1. use the recommended way of passing parameters,
2. try running the query with just one of the `LIKE` conditions at a time; verify that results are as you expect,
3. ensure that the parameters you are passing contain what you expect.

Aside from that: Posting your schema and data—since it's only 3 rows—couldn't hurt.

Comment: It is vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks, I'm being lazy at the moment, but I appreciate you pointing that out. I'll try the above and get back here.

Comment: Now it returns 0 records, when it should return 2 of the 3 total records in my current sandbox database. All 3 of the records have GLOPolicy = True, but 2 of the 3 have ALPolicy != True. Those two are not showing up with the parenthesis. This is extremely frustrating. ~>:(

Comment: @CODe: is ALPolicy NULL in those 2 cases?

Comment: @Adam: No, they are False. False or NULL would be the same in this case though, correct? Given that they are both not equal to True.

Comment: if they were NULL you'd need to add `OR ALPolicy IS NULL` because of three-valued logic (3VL): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the education, I was unaware of 3lv. Trying to learn as much as I can about SQL as this is my first attempt. :)